# Get vars from items generated with a foreach

Tags: javascript, php, select, foreach

I'm generating a menu with list items generated from a `foreach` on a `select` query.

I'm printing the 'name' of each row. But, I also wanted to store some other data from that row inside variables so when I click on an `<li>` I would get those specific vars.

I would like to do this with Javascript so I don't reload the page.

Here's the code I have so far:

```html
$query = "SELECT * FROM credenciais_sensores where ambiente = '1'";
$results = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

<ul class="treeview-menu">
  <?php foreach ($results as $result) {
    $local = $result['local'];
    $local = substr($local,0,7);
    echo "<li><a class='post' href='#'>".$local."</a></li>";
  }?>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
   <?php
    foreach ($results as $result){
         $local = $result['local'];
         $local = substr($local,0,7); ?>
         <li><a class="post" href="#<?=$local;?>"><?=$local;?></a></li>
         <div id="<?=$local;?>">some details...</div>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>

 <?php  foreach ($results as $result){
             $local = $result['local'];
             $local = substr($local,0,7); ?>
             <div id="<?=$local;?>">some details...</div>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right, you want to bind data from the DB/backend to each menu's item element you've created in the foreach loop, then on item element click event, get the item's specific data. if that what you've meant so there are more than one way to go. for now, i will show you one example: when you're creating the item elements you can create data attribute to hold the data as a stringify object and parse it on click event, in the PHP part i've create a mock results array with inner arrays for the example, the "other_data" key contains the data you want to bind to the item element, then in the foreach loop we add "data-other" attribute to contains the other data as an strigify object. i've committed the "substr" function for the example, you can uncommitt it later. the new div with the "display-data" id is just for printing the data of each item on click event:

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
<?php
$results = array(
    array(
        'local' => 'some local 1',
        'other_data' => array(
            'other_data1' => 'some other data 1 from local 1',
            'other_data2' => 'some other data 2 from local 1'
        )
    ),
    array(
        'local' => 'some local 2',
        'other_data' => array(
            'other_data1' => 'some other data 1 from local 2',
            'other_data2' => 'some other data 2 from local 2'
        )
    )
);
$item = '';
foreach ($results as $result){
    $local = $result['local'];
    //$local = substr($local,0,7);
    $other_data = json_encode($result['other_data']);
    $item .= "<li><a class='post' href='#' data-other='$other_data'>$local</a></li>";
}
echo $item;
?>
</ul>
<div id="display-data"></div>
```

in the JS part, we're running a for loop on all of the menu's item elements and add click event so when we will click an item we will get the specific data, then we parse it so we can use it as an object, in the example we print the item's specific data as a string in the div element ("display-data" id) on click event:

```
(function(){
    var item = [], item_data = '', item_data_obj = {}, display = {};
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
        display = document.getElementById('display-data');
        item = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
        for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
            item[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
                item_data = this.getAttribute('data-other');
                item_data_obj = JSON.parse(item_data);
                display.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + ' :' + item_data;
            })
        }
    })
})()
```